# Show a JFrame while waitFor another process to end

Tags: java, multithreading

In my application when the backup button is pressed, it take some time to create the database backup, so I need to display a jframe which contains "Please Wait.." message, and want it to dispose when the backup process is completed. Following is my code, but it never shows the jframe, but application is stuck until the process ends.

```
try {

            WaitView wait = new WaitView();
            wait.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            wait.setVisible(true);

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c mysqlbackup.bat", null, new File("C:\\MySQLBackups"));            
            p.waitFor();

            wait.dispose();

            MessageService.showMessageDialog(MessageService.BACKUP_SUCCESSFUL, "Successful", "info");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the code in SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c mysqlbackup.bat", null, new File("C:\\MySQLBackups"));            
        p.waitFor();

        wait.dispose();

        MessageService.showMessageDialog(MessageService.BACKUP_SUCCESSFUL, "Successful", "info");
```

But actually it's better to run succh ong tasks in a separate thread. Check SwingWorker examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as StanislavL instructed above I have modified the code as below, And It Worked!

```
        final WaitView wait = new WaitView();
        wait.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        wait.setVisible(true);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c mysqlbackup.bat", null, new File("C:\\MySQLBackups"));
                    p.waitFor();

                    wait.dispose();

                    MessageService.showMessageDialog(MessageService.BACKUP_SUCCESSFUL, "Successful", "info");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(HomeView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(HomeView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
```